# Validation at the time of Clicking Submit on Model Popup?

Tags: c#, angular

I need to check for **Validation** in a Popup Model that either **Description can be Null or Attachment can be null**. **NOT BOTH Simaltaneously**. How should I do that?

Following is my code for the **Model Popup**:

```
<div class="modal-body delete-model">

                    <form action="/NewsFeed/AddtoNewsFeed" method="post" class="modalclass">
                        <div>
                            <label class="control-label" for="Description">Title</label>
                            <span class="Required" style="color:red;"> *</span>
                            <input type="text" name="Title" required placeholder="Title" />
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label class="control-label" for="Description">Description</label>
                            <span class="Required" style="color:red;"> *</span>
                            <textarea name="Description" id="Description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" style="max-width:100%; max-height:60px;"></textarea>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label class="control-label" for="txtDescription">Attachment</label>
                            <div class="imgWrap">
                                <img src="" id="ImgPrvPP" class="img-responsive" />
                            </div>
                            <button type="button" value="" class="btn btn-default">
                                <input type="file" style="opacity:0; position:absolute;" id="fileToUpload" />   Attach Image <i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </button>
                            <input type="hidden" id="Images" name="Images" />

                        </div>

                        <button> Create NewsFeed</button>

                        @*<input type="submit" class="btn add-comment" value="Add NewsFeed">*@
                    </form>

                </div>
```

Comment: javascript is your friend in this situation if you want to avoid a postback - are you ok doing that?

Comment: which language you want to use handle validation `javascript jquery or Angular`.

Comment: javascript or angular???!!!

Comment: I am honestly open to both.